# Why my text of delete button be changed to default when I scroll and scroll back UITableView

Tags: ios

I write a UITableView (I hard code some thing for demo), with 20 row. I change text of delete button to "Remove", default is "Delete". I create two button "Top" and "Bottom" to scroll table view to top and bottom. When I swipe line 1, "Remove" button appear. After that, I touch Bottom button to scroll table view to bottom. And I touch Top button to scroll again to top. Now, my delete button's text change to "Delete" (default). Can you help me fix this error.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface ViewController (){
    UITableView* uitableView;
    UIButton* goToTopButton;
    UIButton* goToBottomButton;
}

- (void) goToTopButtonTouched;
- (void) goToBottomButtonTouched;

@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)loadView{
    [super loadView];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    uitableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    uitableView.delegate  = self;
    uitableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:uitableView];

    goToTopButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    goToTopButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 30);
    [goToTopButton setTitle:@"Top" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [goToTopButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToTopButtonTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:goToTopButton];

    goToBottomButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    goToBottomButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 80, 30);
    [goToBottomButton setTitle:@"Bottom" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [goToBottomButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToBottomButtonTouched) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:goToBottomButton];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    NSLog(@"MEMORY WARING");
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString* cellReuseId = @"cellReuse";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellReuseId];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellReuseId];
    }
    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 20;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return @"Remove";
}

- (void)goToTopButtonTouched{
    [uitableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
}

- (void)goToBottomButtonTouched{
    [uitableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:19 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:NO];
}


@end
```

Comment: I don't see the code where you are changing the delete button title to "Remove".

Comment: This is code to set title of delete button (button appear when swipe cell in horizontal):
`- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return @"Remove";
}`

Comment: Please help me. I can't find solution for this problem. I debug and see it not go to `titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath` when I scroll UITableView by touch buttons.

Comment: What happens if you animate the scrolling instead?

Comment: If I scroll by code with animate:YES, it still same problem. If I scroll by hand, it no problem. But I want to scroll by code.